# Автозаполнение Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, h2

Суть такая - Есть проект на java - интернет магазин книг, на нем я учился писать CRUDы. Написан на сервлетах и подключен к mysql. 
Необходимо что бы при скачивании из репозитория , таблицы заполнялись определенными данными. Я знаю что могу экспортировать таблицы, но нужно именно что бы они заполнялись из другого источника. Как это можно сделать? 
Я прочитал что есть встроенная таблица h2 , то есть если я правильно понял ее можно встроить в сам проект и она будет хранить данные. 
Можно как-то сделать так, что бы при развертывания и запуска проекта брались данные из h2 и передавались в mysql ?
Если вопрос глупый, то вспомните, что все мы учились и задавали глупые вопросы)

Comment: *нужно именно что бы они заполнялись из другого источника. Как это можно сделать?* Ну вариантов два. Либо приложение копирует эти данные в БД, либо сервер БД делает это по команде приложения. *Можно как-то сделать так, что бы при развертывания и запуска проекта брались данные из h2 и передавались в mysql ?* Да, можно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно что бы данные заполнялись по определенному действию - например при старте приложени.

Посмотрите на готовые решения типа: 
[Flywaydb](https://flywaydb.org/), [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/)

Comment: Благодарю за то что дали направление